# Update view (Mithriljs) from server (playframework)

Tags: playframework, mithril.js

First I want to say that I am new to web development, so I may use a wrong vocabulary.

I would like to initiate an action from my server to send database modifications to the client to update the view.

I am trying to respect the SPA (Single Page Application) model, so all my view are generated by mithriljs.

I will have some outside modification on my database, what would be the best way to update my view without refreshing the browser?

I use playframework on the server side.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mithriljs - does it work similar to Angular where the View is updated automatically when the underlying model is updated? If yes, you could of course go for a WebSocket connection - your Play app pushes data to the client -> data is put into the model -> view is updated according to the model

Comment: Yes it works that way. Thanks for your answer. I will take a look at WebSocket. Do you recommend a special library for websocket in javascript?

Comment: Well if Mithriljs has some component for this you can use it of course. But even if not - WebSocket connections can be implemented in couple of lines in plain JavaScript - look here: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html - you can also use this to test your server-side

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple to use Mithril with any push-technology. As mentioned by Anton, you can make a simple WebSocket connection and listen for data in a function. Then you process it, updating your data models, and if everything's ok, just call [m.redraw](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.redraw.html) and it's done. Something like this: (using the example at https://www.websocket.org/echo.html)

```
// A simple model, an array of messages:
var messages = m.prop([]);

function onMessage(evt) {
    var message = evt.data;
    // Some validation, only strings allowed
    if (typeof message === 'string' || message instanceof String) {
        messages().push(message);
        // All ok, redraw
        m.redraw();
    }
}
```

Then your mithril view will look like:

```
var WebSocketMessages = {
    view: function() { 
        m("ul", messages().map(function(message) {
            return m("li", message);
        }))
    }
}
```

And to display it:

```
m.mount(document.body, WebSocketMessages);
```

Comment: I'm getting: "TypeError: m.prop is not a function"

Comment: Yes, this example is outdated, from the old 1.x Mithril. Use a normal array var to store the messages instead.